# Stuck on building a customer support chatbot from scratch using reddit dataset

Tags: machine-learning, rnn, chatbot

I've a trained model who can mimic day to day conversation occurring on reddit. But, here my problem is that I want it to reply to a specific use cases based on the vocabulary it had learned.

Summary:-
I am building a college chatbot, and there are many use cases. I've trained a model on reddit dataset, and now I've a model who can mimic reddit conversation. But, I want it to map it's vocabulary to one of my use cases. How should I tackle this scenario?

Any idea? Please help, I've tried searching the internet for days, but no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site! I'm going to make some assumptions here to clarify your question and attempt to give you some guidance: it sounds like (1) you are working with a general chatbot framework and (2) that framework has been trained on a dataset that contains text from reddit.

So, what you need to do is now take that framework and train it again on your own custom dataset (relating to colleges?). I'm assuming that the training can be done based on using a chatbot framework that has this flexibility.

At this point it would beneficial if you posted (1) which chatbot framework you are using and (2) tell us about your data. Do you have a lot of it? Is it in question and answer format?

Answer (score 1):

this answer may be late, but  one really good way of going about this problem would be to develop a transformer network, read the paper " attention is all you need " by google, there are a lot of datasets available online, you can either use them or you can create your own dataset by crawling Reddit or some other social networking site or anything, focus only on data that comes under your use case, don't take in random conversations in your dataset ( yes our dataset should be in conversation form )